# Bring up headless Pi 3B w/Raspbian Jessie – ssh gets "connection refused"

Tags: ssh, headless

This is my first time trying to use a Raspberry Pi (I have a 3B). I downloaded Raspbian Jessie, wrote the image to a micro SD card, installed the card in the Pi, and plugged in the network and power (I'd like to bring it up headless). It has an address on the network and I can ping it, but when I try to ssh I get "connection refused". I was under the impression that ssh would be enabled by default. Is there anything I can do at this point other than plugging in a monitor and keyboard?

Comment: [Raspbian Pixel Security Udate](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/a-security-update-for-raspbian-pixel/)